# What is the shorthand for the first argument of the previous comment in bash? last is '$!'

Tags: linux, replace, special-characters, vi

What is the special character which indicate first ?

if we do

```
$ vi .bashrc
$ source !$
```

this !$ will replaced by .bashrc
because ! means previous line(am I correct?), $ means last word (for sure)

then what is first?

I want to insert some string in every line in vi editor using
`:%s/find-key-word/replaced-keyword/g`

in here, if I put
`:%s/$/example/g`
in vi editor, it will append in all lines with example.

I want to insert all in front of all string every line.

I know I can use visual block `(ctrl+v)` and select all front lines and insert `(shift+i)` insert some word and escape(esc) will do the same... but I want to do in one shot..

please let me know how to do..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Indicate first *line*? Indicate first *character*? Indicate first *what*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions, so you are getting two kinds of answers :)

The bash command history has only a passing similarity to the vi regular expression syntax.

`^` is the beginning of line in vi.   `$` is the end of line in vi.

`!!:0` is one way of accessing the first word of the previous command in bash

`!$` is one way of accessing the last word of the previous command in bash

Answer (score 1):

To indicate beginning of line, the symbol used is:

```
^
```

See an example:

```
$ cat a
hello!
this is me
testing some
stuff
$ sed 's/^/XXX/' a
XXXhello!
XXXthis is me
XXXtesting some
XXXstuff
```

Answer (score 0):

The character you are looking for is `^`.

For example, `:%s/^/example/g` will prepend all lines with the string `example`.

In bash, `!^` refers to the first argument of the previous command, and `!$` the last argument.